# Creating geometry from GeoJSON but received empty result

Tags: python, shapefile, geojson, shapely

Below is my function, the idea is to read a polygon shapefile, and generate some random points (get their coordinates) within each of the polygon feature in the shapefile.

```
from shapely.geometry import shape

def get_polygon_interior_points(self):
    
    all_int_points = list()

    file = ogr.Open(self.output_path_shp)
    layer = file.GetLayer(0)

    for i in range(layer.GetFeatureCount()) :
        feature = layer.GetFeature(i)
        polygon_json = feature.ExportToJson()
        polygon_json = json.loads(polygon_json)
        print(polygon_json)
        polygon_geom = shape(polygon_json['geometry'])
        print(polygon_geom)

        x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = polygon_geom.bounds

        int_points = list()

        while len(int_points) < len(polygon_json['geometry']['coordinates'][0]) / 2 :

            x = random.uniform(x_min, x_max)
            y = random.uniform(y_min, y_max)
            random_point = Point([x, y])
            if random_point.within(polygon_geom): int_points.append([x, y])

        all_int_points.extend(int_points)
    
    self.logger.info(f"\t\tall_int_points length = {len(all_int_points)}")

    return all_int_points
```

However, by running the code below, I keep getting the same error as shown below:

```
{'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[116.98325694032067, 30.524413269923986], [116.98377885614607, 30.524413269923986], [116.98377885614607, 30.524323317916103], [116.983674472981, 30.524323317916103], [116.983674472981, 30.52414341390034], [116.98357008981591, 30.52414341390034], [116.98357008981591, 30.524323317916103], [116.98346570665083, 30.524323317916103], [116.98346570665083, 30.524233365908223], [116.98336132348575, 30.524233365908223], [116.98336132348575, 30.524323317916103], [116.98325694032067, 30.524323317916103], [116.98325694032067, 30.524413269923986]]]}, 'properties': {'id': 2}, 'id': 0}
POLYGON EMPTY
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 250, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 226, in main
    ints = np.asarray(current_detection_tile.get_polygon_interior_points()) if use_int else None
  File "D:\...\detection_tile.py", line 292, in get_polygon_interior_points
    x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = polygon_geom.bounds
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 0)
Exception ignored in: <function BaseGeometry.__del__ at 0x0000022AC8363318>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\...\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\base.py", line 209, in __del__
    self._empty(val=None)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\...\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\base.py", line 194, in _empty
    self._lgeos.GEOSGeom_destroy(self.__geom__)
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000001
```

Comment: Do you have too many brackets for a polygon `[[[`?

Comment: @user30184, 3 sets `[[[` [adheres to the polygon specification](https://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#:~:text=%7B%20%22type%22%3A%20%22Polygon%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22coordinates%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%20%5B100.0%2C%200.0%5D%2C%20%5B101.0%2C%200.0%5D%2C%20%5B101.0%2C%201.0%5D%2C%20%5B100.0%2C%201.0%5D%2C%20%5B100.0%2C%200.0%5D%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%7D)

Comment: Right, there is one more than in WKT.

Comment: I tried to paste the GeoJSON part into geojsonlint.com but it says that it is invalid.

Comment: I got the same. After changing the single quotes to double quotes it threw the error: `Line 1: Polygons and MultiPolygons should follow the right-hand rule`. It is however valid in QGIS. Unfortunately, I can't test the function in the question because I don't know which library `shape` is from.

Comment: @Matt Hi there, thanks a lot for your comment, `shape` comes from shapely.geometry, would you mind letting me know if that works for you? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you include a download link for the original shapefile in your question? Using a shapefile that I generated from the GeoJSON does not give any error.